# Передача данных с PHP (Yii2) в Vue.js

Tags: php, yii2, vue.js

Постоянно возникает необходимость передать данные модели Yii2 во Vue.js. Ранее я справлялся с этим подгружая всё через Ajax. Но теперь появилась острая необходимость передавать данные напрямую. Способы которые я находил в интернете, для меня не работают. Надеюсь мне кто-то сможет помочь.

Больше интересует как передать php-данные в директивы и аттрибуты vue

Comment: "Напрямую" это и есть через Аякс. Php это сервернный язык он отрабатывает только на сервере и на момент когда у вас отображается страница php уже отработал. И "трубы" по которым можно получить эти данные это Аякс и/или вебсокеты.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Я понимаю, я имел ввиду найти способ передать php-данные в атрибуты в таком формате, чтобы vue их отловил и обработал.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Потому что как только я прописываю директиву или добавляю двоеточие для аттрибута, php-данные перестают приниматься.

Comment: можете добавить пример кода как вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: так понимаю Вы хотите собирать страницу на сервере и отдавать страницу уже c данными. Это значит, что нужно на сервере делать php вставки типа `<div v-if="this.$route.matched.length == 0">
            <?php $content ?>
        </div>`

Comment: вот пример [вывода](https://github.com/developeruz/yii-vue-app/blob/master/views/layouts/main.php)

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Например, ситуация какая заставила меня задуматься. Мне необходимо конкатенировать url от php, с id модели от vue

Comment: *конкатенировать url от php, с id модели от vue*  ой, так делать уже не надо.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Я понимаю что звучит, как будто я вообще пошел не в ту степь:) Но у меня стоит острая необходимость так делать. Url обрабатывает у меня Yii2, он его формирует по правилам как я прописал в конфигах. А Id в vue содержится, потому что у меня gridview сделана на vue. Короче нужно ссылку добавить для каждой модели.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Задача стоит прописать нечто подобное `:href="<?= Url::toRoute(['/admin/delete']) ?> + '/' + row.id"`

Comment: во-первых `:href="<?='echo(Url::toRoute(['/admin/delete'])) ?>' + '/' + row.id"` во-вторых не думаю что тако получится, потому что  row.id еще нет когда приходит шаблон.

Comment: php отдаст что то типа :href="'http://site.com/admin/delete' + '/' + row.id" будет ли row.id на момент инициализации шаблона?

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Да, все "было бы" хорошо, но как только я добавляю двоеточие к атрибуту, php код перестает восприниматься.

Comment: а есть пример в гите?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89888/discussion-between-human-and-kostiantyn-okhotnyk).

Comment: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520258/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-vue-component-instance-in-laravel-blade) советуют делать через props без двоеточий. это вывод laravel, но по идее аналогии думаю можно попробовать и на yii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем-то ответ мне подсказал [@KostiantynOkhotnyk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183125/kostiantyn-okhotnyk)

Чтобы написать php код в директиве vue.js, необходимо php код обернуть в одинарные кавычки.

Например:

```
<a v-bind:href="'<?= $url ?>/' + row.param">Ссылка</a>
```